# Running Thunar custom actions in a directory located at afc://

Tags: xubuntu, iphone, thunar-custom-actions

I am running Xubuntu 14.04.
I have an iPhone 5 with iOS 7.1

I can mount the phone and see my photos and videos.
I can drag the photos and videos to another directory in home and then manipulate them.

I'd rather be able to choose a custom action to manipulate the photos and videos then copy or move them to home. (It would be ok to use a custom action to move them and then manipulate them.)

The problem is that I do not know how to run a script or perform a custom thunar action on a directory that is located at:

```
afc://6a244e0b3a6637cff9cf954d83a2fbf1faa0c2aa/DCIM/103APPLE/
```

In earlier versions of Ubuntu I was able to use the .gvfs location in a script, but that no longer seems to be available in 14.04